# HOw can I decode an IR remote control button press on the Elektofreaks cutebot robot?

Tags: javascript, bbc-microbit

I bought an Elecfreaks cutebot robot for grandchildren.
The BBC:microbit board is its brain.

The company sells an IR Remote Control, but so far I don't know if all the button presses can be decoded. The sample Javascript program shows decoding only for the four arrows and OK button on the R/C.

Does anynone know if there is a way to decode on this platform button presses of other IR R/C-s such as for TVs, LED strings, etc. and how?

Electrofreaks website:
https://www.elecfreaks.com/learn-en/microbitKit/smart_cutebot/cutebot_case14.html#materials

Comment: You should be able to decode them, however you will need to know what is what. I assume the company tells you what IR code maps to what event name.  It's also hard to tell how the data is formatted without any sample data.  The "can I decode it" entirely depends on what the "it" in that sentence looks like.

Comment: `cuteBot.IRButtons` contains the following One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Zero, Plus, Minus, Left, Right, Up, Down, Back, Menu (every item on the remote provided with the kit)

Comment: for other IR remotes, its possible using other extensions (makerbit-ir-receiver might work?) but you'd need to figure out the pins used for the ir receiver on the cutebot

Comment: The BBC:microbit 5 x 5 LED matrix is also a light sensor. Is it sensitive to infrared? If so, what Javascript program can provide the code associated with any make R/C button press?

Comment: "cuteBot.IRButtons contains the following One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Zero, Plus, Minus, Left, Right, Up, Down, Back, Menu (every item on the remote provided with the kit)"

Yes. I checked and it is posible rto check fopr all those buttons on MAKE or Javascript.

Thank you.

Comment: "for other IR remotes, its possible using other extensions (makerbit-ir-receiver might work?) but you'd need to figure out the pins used for the ir receiver on the cutebot "

Which pins on the cutebot and where?

Alo, why pins if I use am IR R/C and the robot has an IR receiver?

Comment: If you have follow-up questions, you should update the question instead of asking in a comment. The IR sensor on the bot does have a pin number, it's just hard-coded into the module. Look at the source code on GitHub and you should be able to find the pin number used.